# Components Only get drawn when hovered over

Tags: java, swing

Can someone explain why my components only get drawn when I hover over where they are supposed to be?

I setup a borderless frame than can be dragged anywhere and I'm trying to create an exit button at the top right but it doesn't get drawn until I hover over it. I paint to the JFrame a background image, then draw my button and set the whole thing visible.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame
{
    private Image Background = null;
    private static Point Offset = new Point();

    public GUI() {
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        AddListeners();
        SetCustomTheme();
        LoadBackground();
        Layout();
        pack();
        this.setSize(300, 300);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void Layout() {
        GroupLayout Info = new GroupLayout(this.getContentPane());
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(Info);
        JButton Button = new JButton();

        Info.setHorizontalGroup(
            Info.createSequentialGroup()
               .addComponent(Button)
         );

        Info.setVerticalGroup(
            Info.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(Button)
        );
    }

    private void SetCustomTheme() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        }
    }

    private void LoadBackground() {
        try {
            Background = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Images/meh.png"));
        } catch (Exception Ex) {

        }
    }

    private void SetCustomIcon() {
        Image Icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Images/lol.jpg");
        setIconImage(Icon);
    }

    private void AddListeners() {
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
              Offset.x = e.getX();
              Offset.y = e.getY();
            }
          });

        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
              Point p = getLocation();
              setLocation(p.x + e.getX() - Offset.x, p.y + e.getY() - Offset.y);
            }
          });
    }

    @Override public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(Background, 0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(), null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. All interactions with the UI must be executed from within the Event Dispatching Thread
2. You should avoid extending from top level containers, like `JFrame`, instead, use `JPanel` instead.
3. Failing to honor the `paint` chain contract is preventing any child components from begin painted
4. The preferred method to override for performing custom painting is `paintComponent`

You might like to have a read through

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [The Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Try something like this instead;

```
public class BadPaint01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BadPaint01();
    }

    public BadPaint01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                Image Icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Images/lol.jpg");
                frame.setIconImage(Icon);
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new GUI());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class GUI extends JPanel {

        private Image Background = null;
        private static Point Offset = new Point();

        public GUI() {
            AddListeners();
            SetCustomTheme();
            LoadBackground();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 300);
        }

        private void Layout() {
            GroupLayout Info = new GroupLayout(this);
            setLayout(Info);
            JButton Button = new JButton();

            Info.setHorizontalGroup(
                    Info.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(Button));

            Info.setVerticalGroup(
                    Info.createParallelGroup()
                    .addComponent(Button));
        }

        private void SetCustomTheme() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }
        }

        private void LoadBackground() {
            try {
                Background = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Images/meh.png"));
            } catch (Exception Ex) {
            }
        }

        private void AddListeners() {
            this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    Offset.x = e.getX();
                    Offset.y = e.getY();
                }
            });

            this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    Point p = getLocation();
                    setLocation(p.x + e.getX() - Offset.x, p.y + e.getY() - Offset.y);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            g.drawImage(Background, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
        }
    }
}
```

You also might like to have read through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), you're not going to make any friends by ignoring them ;)

Comment: Then why does Netbeans extend from the JFrame instead of JPanel? :S

Comment: Because it's not an invalid operation, just an ill adviced one. There are times when you may want to add additional functionality to the `JFrame`, but in you're case you're not adding any value.  Also, painting onto top level containers is a bad idea because 1- They're not double buffered and 2- The frame has a `JRootPane` ontop of it, which contains content pane, so any painting you do is either going to be done underneath or on top of the content, which in your case not desirable, as the root pane will hide you work (if you were actually using the the paint mechanism properly.

Comment: Java will allow you to update the UI components from any thread, but it is considered bad practice, there is a contract of understanding between the developer and the API, while you can break this contract, expect things to go pear shape real quickly.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp see "why can my car do 220km an hour then?" ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember well, `ToolKit.getImage` returns an `Image` which may not be completely loaded. When you hover over it, it probably has been loaded in the background meanwhile.
Instead do this (similar to your line for Background):

```
ImageIcon Icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Images/lol.png")));
setIconImage(Icon);
```

(For better understanding you may want to search for `MediaTracker`, which I believe was used to make sure, that the image is loaded completely.)